# Unity Game View Line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity but when I create a map with Tile Map and look at the map in the game view it has some lines

[image]

Comment: Please add some more detail on what is exactly the question and the issue you are having. Get some code examples, implementation flow sequence steps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's tilemap aliasing, usually goes away when you try a standard resolution in the gameview, which you already have but try 1x scale, also try something like 720p, 1080p or an actual monitor resolution and make sure the game view is set to "Fixed resolution". If the aliasing disappears, you will know it only appears at weird resolutions and you won't have to worry about it.

If it doesn't, theses are some of the things you can try:

1. First make sure that the filtering mode for your tilemap sprite/s is set to point.
2. Add a new material to the tilemap gameobject and set it's shader to Sprites/Default, then check the "pixel snap" box.
3. Try the pixel perfect camera https://blog.unity.com/technology/pixel-perfect-2d
4. Set the grid cell gap on x and y axis to a very small negative number, like -0.0001

If all of these doesn't work, I think you will have to use the sprite packer to pack your tilemap into a sprite atlas and make it so that there are gaps between each tile. If you wanna know why that is: https://forum.unity.com/threads/tilemap-has-tearing-between-tiles-even-with-pixel-snap.499154/#post-3292216